# How can I read from Stream and change the encoding?

Tags: java, encoding, stream, filepath

I need to read all files in one directory like D:/Test... and I have to detect if some word(no matter what) is contained in the files.
So far so good I did this, but the question is what if some file that I iterate is with different encoding(not "UTF-8").

The program will say that the word is not contained in file? But this word will be there and this answer will be wrong.
So I have to iterate with different encoding maybe?

Comment: Yes, or you can try to use some library that tries to determine which encoding the file is in, and then use that encoding to read the file.

Comment: It depends. A lot of encodings, including UTF-8, are ASCII based, so if the file consists of ASCII letters only, it doesn’t matter how the non-ASCII bytes would get interpreted, if they were present. So for a lot of encodings and files, you will get the correct result anyway. For files containing non-ASCII characters, you usually get exceptions when trying to interpret them as UTF-8. That applies especially to the new `Files` API that is preconfigured to throw, rather than the old classes which default to replace invalid characters.

Comment: Yes, Holger this is true, but what if I find file with "UTF-16LE" encoding. I have this word in file, but program says - no it's not. I need some help for situations when encoding is not UTF-8 and program have to try with different encoding.

Comment: Well, on most systems, files don’t tell their encoding (or whether they are text files at all), so you would have to do guesswork, if you want to handle such cases automatically (instead of consider it the user’s responsibility). As Kayaman mentioned, there might be libraries to help making an educated guess, but you may also implement your own heuristic, but in either case, you have to live with the fact that this can only support a limited set of encodings. Unless you’re talking about something like html or xml files, containing a declaration of their encoding.